# Passing cell value from datagridview to textbox without clicking the cell

Tags: vb.net

My program imports excel files and after this, all the data in excel has been shown in 
`DatagridView`. I want a specific cell to pass its value to `Textbox`.

I have tried using  `Me.TextBox3.Text = DataGridView1.Rows(15).Cells(2).Value.ToString()`
But there's an error which is cannot be converted in string..
row15, column2 has text..

Comment: Have you tried `Me.TextBox3.Text = DataGridView1.Rows[14].Cells[1].Value` ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this error (error converting into string) is because the value is `Nothing`. The indexes begin in 0, so, as Andrey commented, for reaching row 15 and second column you have to do it this way:

```
Me.TextBox3.Text = DataGridView1.Rows(15).Cells(1).Value.ToString()
```

Comment: @CindyPascual This answer worked for you? Then mark it as a correct answer please.